# Apache Server giving forbidden errors when trying to access site

Tags: apache2

Can someone help me figure out how to fix my Apache server? When trying to browse to a page hosted by the server, I got a 403 Forbidden error. I think it is related to a Tomcat AJP proxy. I have the following errors in my log.

> [Thu Aug 18 18:27:21.290498 2022] [access_compat:error] [pid 206988] [client 192.168.49.243:54054] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: proxy:ajp://10.11.1.209:8009/test.txt
> [Thu Aug 18 18:27:21.322610 2022] [access_compat:error] [pid 206988] [client 192.168.49.243:54054] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: proxy:ajp://10.11.1.209:8009/favicon.ico
> [Thu Aug 18 18:27:28.314991 2022] [access_compat:error] [pid 206989] [client 192.168.49.243:54056] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: proxy:ajp://10.11.1.209:8009/

I remember configuring a Tomcat proxy months ago, but I don't remember what I did or where to start looking. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Please provide the relevant configuration files.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider I'd be happy to. Which ones are you referring to?